# Retrieve user ID displayed in the URL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page where the admin can see all the members who are registered, that means their information are stored in the database. It is in tabular form with Update links displayed beside each name which redirects to my update.php page with forms. After I click the Update link, I am redirected to my update.php and the URL displays the user id which I need to update :`clinic/update.php?res_id=3`

Now, I have a form in my update.php and I need to get that `res_id=3` displayed in the URL to also be included in my MySQL INSERT STATEMENT in my action script which is add_assessment.php. I have tried using `$ID=$_GET['res_id']` and `$ID=$_POST['res_id']` but none of which is working. Can anybody please tell me what line of code do I have to use? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the value to the form so the `$_POST` or `$_GET` values on `update.php` will not be available to `add_assessment.php`.

---

In `clinic/update.php?res_id=3` output `$_GET['res_id']` as the value in a hidden form field like so:

```
<input type='hidden' name='res_id' value='<?php echo htmlspecialshars($_GET['res_id']); ?>' />
```

Then access it in `add_assessment.php` with `$_POST['res_id']`

**OR**

Append it to the `action='add_assessment.php'` in the form like so:

```
<form action='add_assessment.php?res_id=<?php echo htmlspecialshars($_GET['res_id']); ?>' method='post'>
```

Then access it in `add_assessment.php` with `$_GET['res_id']`

Answer (score 1):

Without having any of your code to go by, I can only suggest stepping through your workflow and using `var_dump` on both `$_GET` and `$_POST` and making sure that the `res_id` is being passed from page to page.